# Html - Helper in Custom ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way to get an instance of the Html-Helper within a custom Model-Binder?

E.g.:

```
public class TranslationModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
       // HtmlHelper helper = new HtmlHelper(?,?);
       object model = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

How can I get the two needed arguments?

Thx for any tipps!
sl3dg3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you could, it would be wrong.

HtmlHelper is a tool for the view where it renders the Model while the binder does the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

The model binder runs much before the view executes so that you don't have a `ViewContext` yet which allows you to obtain an `HtmlHelper`. You could probably fake this context but that is not something I would recommend you doing. You could have an `UrlHelper` though.

Comment: My intention was actually to use something like Html.Display("MyProperty") in order to have an easy access to the DisplayAttribute. Is there another easy way for this?

Comment: What does `ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext` refer to? It is a view context, but it seems likely not the correct one.

Comment: @sl3dg3, you could use the metadata: `var metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, typeof(YourModel), "MyProperty");`. And then `metadata.DisplayName` will give you what you need.

Comment: @Matt Greer, `ParentActionViewContext` is assigned only inside child actions (actions invoked with the `Html.Action` or `Html.RenderAction` helpers) and is null inside normally invoked actions (action that you invoke directly like `/home/index`).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrow: Thx! I didn't think of `ModelMetaData` :)